# Language and interpretation.

Tags: logic

> Let $L$ be $\{c_1,c_2,P^1,R^2\}$ and consider the interpretation $M_I=<M,0,1,\{0,1\},\{<0,1>,<1,1>\}>$ for $M=\{0,1,2\}$.

I have a few questions regarding how the determine if a formula given is true or not under the former condition, particularly, if I must consider the remaining value ($2$) which is not in $L$ when evaluating whether a formula is true or false. This questions arises from the definitions for some operators, which involve extending the language $L$ to $L^+$ being the last one a language which includes $L$ together with constansts to have all the elements in $M$.

For example the definition of true for $\forall x A$ under an interpretation $MI$ is given as follows: $M_I(\forall x_kAx_k)=T$ if $M_I^+(A(x_k|c_i))=T$ for every $c_i$ in $L^+$, being $M^+$ and interpreatation of $L^+$ which coincides with $M$ for the elements in common.

$(1)$ For example the formula $\exists x\forall yRyx$ would be false?.
My first answer (intuitive) would be that the formula give is true since exists $1$ and for both $0$ and $1$ we have the relations $<0,1>$, $<1,1>$; but a second answer (according to the definition) makes this false because there is no $<2,1>$.

$(2)$ What about $\forall x \forall y \forall z((Rxy\wedge Ryz)\implies Rxz)?$.The only way to make the conjuction true is with $x=0, y=1, z=1$ and $<0,1>$ is a relation so this appears to be true.

$(3)$ $\forall x \exists y Rxy$. I have a similar problem to the one I said in example 1, this is, should I consider the $2$?. If not, this is true (set $y=1$); if $2$ should be considered, since there is no $<2,y>$ for any $y$ this can never be true.

Which leads me to the question: If an interpretation $M_I$ is incomplete (like $M_I$ which left the $2$ out), can we say that all interpretations of $\forall$ under $M$ are false (assuming the operator wasn't negated before)?.

Comment: $(\forall x)((\exists z)R(z,z) \vee R(x,x))$ is true in your example. Also $(\forall z)(c_1 = c_1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question (1) :

> if the formula $∃x∀yRyx$ is false in $M_I$

the answer is : **Yes**.

In the *domain* $M$ of the interpretation we have that it is not true that $2R1$ [i.e. $<2,1>  \notin R^M$].

For (2), you are right.

And also for (3) :

> $∀x∃yRxy$

your ansewer is correct : there is no $y$ such that $2Ry$ [i.e. for no $y$, $<2,y>  \in R^M$].

Now for the "real" question :

> If and interpretation $M_I$ is incomplete (like $M_I$ which left the $2$ out), can we say that all interpretations of $∀$ under $M$ are false (assuming the operator wasn't negated before)?.

**NO**. The interpretation does not "leave out" $2$; it is not necessary that every element of the domain has a "name".

The quantifiers "range over" **all** elements in the domain, irrespective of the fact that they are "named" or not.

Consider the formula :

> $\forall x P(x)$;

it is cleary *false* in the interpretation, because we have an element in $M$ [exactly : $2$] which "is not $P$".

The way the semantic clause is defined is :

> for every object in the domain, we expand provisonally the language with a "name" $c^*$ for it [this is the meaning of $L^+$] and in this way we can "test" for *satisfaction* the formula $A(x)$ for **all** elements in the domain.